# Random Item generator error

Tags: c#, random, formatexception

Okay so basically, I'm making a random item generator for a class project.
Right now the Name generating part doesn't work once it hits 3 or more names.
The error I get is:

> FormatExeption was Unhandled
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
    public static string ID { get; set; }
    public static int Damage { get; set; }
    public static int Defense { get; set; }
    public static string Name;
    public static string Rarity;
    public static int NumberOfNames;
    public static string ItemType;
    public static Random Random = new Random();
    public static List<string> ItemTypeList = new List<string> { "Chest area armor", "Weapon", "Shield", "Head area armor", "Leggings", "Shoes", "Gloves", "Belt", "Ring" };
    public static List<string> WeaponList = new List<string> { "Staff", "Sword", "Dagger", "Wand", "Axe", "Mace" };
    public static List<string> Value1 = new List<string> { "Wooden", "Bronze" };
    public static List<string> Value2 = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel" };
    public static List<string> Value3 = new List<string> { "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium", "Titanium", "Arcane", };
    public static List<string> ArmorValue = new List<string> { "Cloth", "Leather", "Iron", "Silver", "Steel", "Titanium", "Arcane", "Dragon Glass", "Titanium" };
    public static List<string> Name1 = new List<string> { "Stupid", "Great", "Powerful", "Epic", "Masterfull", "Mighty", "Bountiful", "Foreverlasting", "Pointless", "Useless" };
    public static List<string> Name2 = new List<string> { "Things", "Power", "Proportions", "Torment", "Legs", "Turnament", "Shit", "Crazyness", "Awesomeness" };
    public static List<string> NameLenght3List = new List<string> { "Ragnarok", "Power", "Bondage", "Noobs", "Great Weakness", "Error", "404", "Torture", "SHIT STATS(No idea since I'm not good enough to programm stats based on names)", "The Dark Lord", "Emperor", "Monkey Kong", "I ran out of words", "Blablabla" };

    public static string ItemGenerator(int droprarity)
    {
        int dropRarity = droprarity;
        NumberOfNames = NumberOfNamesGenerator(dropRarity);
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfNames);
        Rarity = RarityGenerator(dropRarity);
        ItemType = ItemTypeGenerator();
        if (ItemType == "Sword")
        {
            ItemType = WeaponList[Random.Next(0, WeaponList.Count)];
        }
        Name = NameGenerator();
        return Name;

    }
    public static string RarityGenerator(int dropRarity)
    {
        switch (dropRarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Rarity = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                Rarity = "Common";
                break;
            case 3:
                Rarity = "Uncommon";
                break;
            case 4:
                Rarity = "Elite";
                break;
            case 5:
                Rarity = "Rare";
                break;
            case 6:
                Rarity = "Legendary";
                break;
        }

        return Rarity;
    }
    public static string ItemTypeGenerator()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", ItemTypeList[Random.Next(0, ItemTypeList.Count)]);
    }
    public static int NumberOfNamesGenerator(int dropRarity)
    {
        switch (dropRarity)
        {
            case 1:
                NumberOfNames = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 4);
                break;
            case 3:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 4);
                break;
            case 4:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 5);
                break;
            case 5:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 5);
                break;
            case 6:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 6);
                break;
        }
        return NumberOfNames;
    }
    public static string NameGenerator()
    {
        int nameNR = NumberOfNames;
        if (nameNR == 2)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Rarity, ItemType);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 3)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3}", Rarity, ItemType, NameLenght3List[Random.Next(0, NameLenght3List.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 4)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3} {4}", Rarity, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 5)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3} {4} {5}", Rarity, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 6)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3} {4} {5} {6}", Rarity, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else
        {
            string ErrorSword = "Error Sword/Armor/blablabla";
            return ErrorSword;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number;
        number = Random.Next(1, 6);
        Name = ItemGenerator(number);
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
        Console.ReadLine();;
    }
    }
}
```

The error Occurs at public static string NameGenerator()

Comment: Just curious, is this game related code?

Comment: Side note: in the future please make sure to search for error message before asking the question and provide *minimal* code that demonstrates the problem (see [MCVE] for guidance).

Answer (score 3):

```
 else if (nameNR == 3)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3}", Rarity, ItemType, NameLenght3List[Random.Next(0, NameLenght3List.Count)]);
    }
    else if (nameNR == 4)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3} {4}", Rarity, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
    }
    else if (nameNR == 5)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3} {4} {5}", Rarity, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
    }
    else if (nameNR == 6)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3} {4} {5} {6}", Rarity, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
    }
```

In all of these `string.Format()` methods, you're skipping over `{2}` and going from `{1}` to `{3}`, which is not allowed. Changed them to 
`return string.Format("{0} {1} of {2}..."` and so on.

Comment: You beat me to the punch. Dang fast typers.. lol JK.

Comment: I feel so blind right now, Thanks :)

Comment: No prob. I write enterprise security and banking aplications, and have been bitten by the string format index issue. SOmtimes we see it because it makes sense in our head, and a third eye is all you need. Part of coding. :)

Comment: @MartinRingenberg Please mark one of the answers as "the answer" to close the question. Either mine or Casey's since they both were on to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You are skippin the {2} position in your string format. I think that is the issue.

Example:

```
 return string.Format("{0} {1} of {2}", Rarity, ItemType, NameLenght3List[Random.Next(0, NameLenght3List.Count)]);
```

Not as you have it:

```
 return string.Format("{0} {1} of {3}", Rarity, ItemType, NameLenght3List[Random.Next(0, NameLenght3List.Count)]);

enter code here
```

That makes sense why it occurs at 3 or more.

Comment: FML thanks, so tried from coding that I'm already blind XD